# Different Bayes Factor values for correlation with the same JZS approach

Tags: r, correlation, bayes-factors

Trying to get the Bayes Factor for a correlation between two variables in my data, I tried three different functions. All implement the Jeffreys–Zellner–Siow (JZS) prior, but I get quite different results with the three approaches. Two questions:

1. Is this suspicious, or is it reasonable that they produce different values, as the implementations are slightly different?
2. Is there a consensus on the best measure to use?

My data:

```
a=rnorm(100,1,2)
b=rnorm(100,.8,1.5)
myData <- data.frame(a=a, b=b)
```

I try the `jzs_corbf` function, described and implemented [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22798023) ([shorter version](http://dsquintana.com/post/98962697485/how-to-calculate-a-bayes-factor-for-correlations))

```
cor.resu.a_b <- cor.test(myData$a, myData$b, method=c("pearson"))
cor.resu.a_b$estimate
n = 100
r = cor.resu.a_b$estimate
jzs_corbf(r,n)
[1] 0.08206358
```

I also tried the convenience function from the `BayesFactor` package:

```
require(BayesFactor)
regressionBF(b ~ a, data = myData, progress=FALSE)

Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] a : 0.2181081 ±0%

Against denominator:
  Intercept only 
---
Bayes factor type: BFlinearModel, JZS
```

And I also tried the a function described [recently](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4891395/) ([code](https://osf.io/9d4ip/))

```
bf10JeffreysIntegrate(n=100, r=r)

      cor 
0.1297927
```

While in this case the differences are only numerical, in my real data I get quite big differences that make it more difficult to decide on an interpretation.

[Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184950/calculating-bayes-factor-from-a-correlation-coefficient)